# How to store Powershell output to a variable?

Tags: powershell

I'm validating a markdown using Powershell script and I use below command line

```
markdownlint.cmd "c:\index.md"
```

And it returns output like below

```
levels should only increment by one level at a time [Expected: h2; Actual: h3]

index.md: 4: MD003/heading-style/header-style Heading style 
[Expected: setext; Actual: atx]
```

I want to export the output log to a variable, in which I'd like to test like

```
if( $output -contains '*Expected*')
{

Write-Host "contains errors"
}
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to export to a variable within code, How can I do it?

Options I tried

`$output = Invoke-Expression "markdownlint.cmd 'c:\index.md' "`

```
    markdownlint.cmd 'c:\index.md' | Export-csv c:\test.csv
```

This did not work.

Note: markdownlint.cmd is CMD line Env.

Answer (score 3):

Simply enclose your batch command and args in parentheses

```
$output = (markdownlint.cmd "c:\index.md")

if( $output -match 'Expected') { 
    Write-Host "contains errors" 
}
```

Single quotes have no special meaning in `cmd.exe`,

so `markdownlint.cmd 'c:\index.md'` fails because it looks for them literally.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately nothings gets assigned to $output. This is my code . ```
npm install -g markdownlint-cli
$output = (markdownlint.cmd "C:\index.md")
Write-Host $output
if( $output -contains '*Expected*')
{

Write-Host "contains errors"
}
```

Comment: You are using the wrong comparison operator, `-contains` checks if the array `$output` has an exact entry `Expected`, use RegEx based `-match` instead. Read [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0):

**Export-csv** is a combination of two commands: **convertTo-csv** piped to **out-file**.

The **markdownlint.cmd "c:\index.md"** is probably not producing a powershell object as output.
From `Get-Help ConvertTo-Csv -Full` I can see **ConvertTo-csv** requires as input a powershell object:

> ```
>  SYNTAX
> ConvertTo-Csv [-InputObject] <PSObject> [[-Delimiter] <Char>] [-NoTypeInformation] [<CommonParameters>]
>
> ConvertTo-Csv [-InputObject] <PSObject> [-NoTypeInformation] [-UseCulture] [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

You can use the

`markdownlint.cmd 'c:\index.md' | out-file 'c:\textfile.txt'`

and then examine the file content and see how you can parse or convert it.

Comment: @lftimie - It wont anything export to file . i want to write the data to a variable within.